# DOM getElementsByTag order consistency

Tags: dom

When doing a getElementsByTag, I see a particular order in the returned nodelist. Can I count on that order being consistent from any particular browser vendor from one release to the next and is there consistency among all browser vendors?

The more generic question is - Is there a spec that the browser vendors follow to guarantee an order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just can asnwer for Firefox: the returned (e.g. elements = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName)) is a live NodeList of found elements in the order they appear in the subtree.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName

I think there is no spec to guarantee an order, because W3C doesn't mention that:

> "getElementsByTagName: Returns a collection of all descendant Elements
>   with a given tag name.
>
> Parameters: tagname -The name of the tag to match on. If the string
>   "*" is given, this method will return all elements in the document.
>
> Return Values: A new NodeList object containing reference to all the
>   Elements found.
>
> This method raises no exceptions.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/level-one-core.html

Comment: I figured as much and wrote my own function to guarantee the order. Too bad really, as the spec should include something as obvious as sequence.